# Replacing using "$" gives weird results

Tags: javascript

I am trying to replace some text like:

`I need the %r for the bike.`

Where `%r` gets replaced with another value.

Lets say I replace `%r` with `$$$$`.

```
var text = 'I need the %r for the bike.';

return text.replace("%r", "$$$$");
```

Instead of getting the expected results of:

`I need the $$$$ for the bike.`

I get:

`I need the $$ for the bike.`

Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$` is a special character in a replacement as you need `$$` to get one resulting `$` sign in the result.  You will need extra `$` chars to get what you want.  See the [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) for `.replace()` for details.

Various special sequences in the replacement string are:

```
$$ - Inserts a "$"
$& - Insert the matched substring
$` - Inserts the portion of the string that precedes the matched substring
$' - Inserts the portion of the string that follows the matched substring
$n - Where n or nn are decimal digits, inserts the nth parenthesized submatch string, provided the first argument was a RegExp object.
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought that the dollar sign only did something when replacing with `REGEXP`.